# Information about androidManifest file

Tags: android, android-activity

i am a new android app developer and i had created one online app. Now i want to upload on google play.. but i am confuse about android manifest file like which field is necesary or required and what is its value.(eg. minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, supports).. My manifest file look like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.javacodegeeks.android.apps.moviesearchapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
          />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".MovieSearchAppActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MoviesListActivity" 
            android:label="Movie List"/>
        <activity android:name=".PersonListActivity" 
            android:label="Movie List"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

can you suugest me more attribute which is required for an app? or can you upload androidManifest file for an online app which is on google play.

Comment: If your app compiles, then your manifest is valid.  If you want to understand each field, go read the official docs.

Comment: thanks for your response.. but for a live app on mobile, i think it requires more field in manifest file. someone told that minSdkVersion should be 11 for uploading on google play... Can you upload one manifest file?? thanks

Comment: minSDKVersion does not need to be 11.  It needs to be whatever your app requires.  If it needed to be 11, 2.x devices would not be able to use Google Play (which isn't the case).  Like I said-  if it compiles, you have a valid manifest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911258/what-happens-if-the-minsdkversion-is-lower-than-the-targetsdkversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.labandroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooseAction"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_action" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MessagingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_messaging" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddContact"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_contact" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddGroup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_contact" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: it gives warning "Attribute minSdkVersion(8) is higher than the project target api level (3)"

Comment: checkout the minimum version when you created the project, It might be bcoz of the version you created with

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest looks fine to me. You can do 1 more think (but it is not compulsory), add `android:targetSdkVersion` tag

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"  android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```